# Update data entry for one month and future months

Tags: database, vba, excel

I think it is a straightforward question that requires some macro modification in my file, I will appreciate your help.

I am using this very useful form for data entry (Data Entry Form (Add/View)): http://www.contextures.com/xlForm02.html

I've adjusted it for my purpose (to track staff movements, changes and new starters), see the file here: http://www.filedropper.com/formsheeteditopttest2-creatingonemastersheetv8forstackoverflow

Every worker has a unique ID and a row per month. In the future the manager of these employees will be able to update the sheet (Input) to reflect any changes that are happening to the person (e.g. promotions, changes of site, change to the role name etc.).

So the two scenarios I am trying to do are for A - update to the current worker, B - adding a new starter.

A - when your UPDATE e.g. job level for one person in e.g. March 2017, this change should be reflected for this person for the rest of the year so for April 2017, May 2017 up to December 2017 etc.

B - When you ADD a new starter (e.g in May, 2017), I would like this starter to be added for each month i.e. May, 2017; June, 2017; July, 2017 up to December 2017 as well.

Any idea what to do to the existing macro code in the file for it to work?

Thanks
 Ewa

Comment: This is very vague to understand without the actual data as we cannot run the code against a blank sheet to find out where the problem is.   Could you narrow down your question?  Provide some data to test it against?

Comment: Hi Kerry, I think the data will explain everything. Have a look at the attached workbook: http://www.filedropper.com/formsheeteditopttest2-creatingonemastersheetv8forstackoverflow
Basically, when your UPDATE e.g.  job level changes in e.g. March 2017, it should be reflected in the data for the rest of the months in the future so for April 2017, May 2017 etc.

When you ADD a new starter, this starter will obviously get the first row for this month (e.g. May, 2017) but I would like this starter t be added for each month in the future i.e. June, 2017, July, 2017 as well. @KerryWhite